# User control filed element is wiped out sometimes in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls, outputcache

We have user control which has so many text box .User control placed in inside the aspx page . It working almost but sometimes ,some of the text values is null when we read it from code behind . but same input is working in next attempt . We have outputcache =VarbyParam in aspx page . i am thinking it may cause the issue  if the controls loaded from cache , code behind cannot get the values . one more thing is not all the text box is affected .

In aspx Page

```
 <%@ OutputCache Duration="2" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

In ascx control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAdjustment" runat="server" Width="71%" onfocus="this.select();" onblur="this.value=formatCurrency(this.value);CalcAdjustedValue()"
                    MaxLength='20' BackColor='<%# isSubject ? System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F5F4EA") : Color.White %>' Enabled="<%# !isSubject %>" 
                    Style="text-align: right" CssClass="compTabField"/>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender16" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="txtAdjustment" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="0123456789$,." />
```

reading values in code behind

```
//clientId is "txtAdjustment"
    private string getValue(string clientId)
    {
        Control ctl = null;
        //ctl = this.FindControl("fv");
        //if (ctl != null)
        ctl = this.FindControl(clientId);
        //else
        //    return string.Empty;

        if (ctl == null)
            return string.Empty;
```

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: I wouldn't put output caching on a form page unless you can donut the form.  I think I've had similar weird problems with it in the past so usually don't cache form pages anymore

Comment: question has been edited and code added

Comment: @Pete ,@jasper seinhorst  i am having more than 10 text boxes but facing issues in some of the text box only .is it possible because of cache.